# Moment js create datetime in certain timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

I have the datetime 2013-08-02 11:23:52, i know that it in MST7MDT timezone. But, when i create `moment("2013-08-02 11:23:52")` i have moment-object in custom user timezone. How I can set timezone during creating moment-object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about moment-timezone,  this does not currently exist in the 0.0.1 release, but [has been requested](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/11).  There is a pending [pull request](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/18), but it has not yet been merged because there is still some lacking functionality.  So you can go try adding that PR manually, or you can wait until it is stable.

You might also consider using one [of the other time zone libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824) instead.